# How to access form item in partial Class within another Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

How to access form item in partial Class within another Class?For instance;

```
public class BusinessLayer{ //I wanna access Login class in here }

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page{ }
```

Comment: I don't know your setup but I would not want to put in a view (aspx page) to my business layer. Try passing data instead.

Comment: Agree with @MartijnB If I absolutely HAD to pass part of the presentation layer to the business layer, then I'd define an interface in the business layer, implement it in the Login class, and pass it as that interface. Even so, avoiding that entirely would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference to the `BusinessLayer` constructor

```
public class BusinessLayer {
  private Login _login;
  public BusinessLayer(Login login) {
    _login = login;
  }
}

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page() {
  public void Method() {
    BusinessLayer layer = new BusinessLayer(this);
    ...
  }
}
```

Note this problem has little / nothing to do with `partial class` types.  The same problem would apply with standard `class` types

Comment: Firstly, @JaredPar thank you very much for help.But i don't create Login instance within BusinessLayer Class.Meantime Login of Web Form Class (Login.aspx) ,BusinessLayer into App_Code folder.